# Include comments in search

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

When searching in VS Code (PowerShell), I would like to include my comments (`#`, `<# #>`) in the result. (due to language used in comments)
have tried to find a setting for this by searching this forum & Google without luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

VS Code:

- Version: 1.26.1
- Commit: 493869ee8e8a846b0855873886fc79d480d342de
- Date: 2018-08-16T18:38:57.434Z
- Electron: 2.0.5
- Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
- Node.js: 8.9.3
- V8: 6.1.534.41
- Architecture: x64

Comment: What do you mean with "include comments in search"? When i use the VSCode Search it also shows results that are comments in the powershell file. Sounds like more of an language problem than a comment problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default if i search something on visual studio code, inside a powershell script which contains comments as you said, it does show up during the search itself.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
It turns out that if I only type in parts of the words I'm looking for I get no hit :(
If I only types 3 letters in the word I get no hit.

Comment: For example:
`code`
#Skapa Dynamisk Maillista (DL) baserad på Title-attributet
Function CreateDynDL_FilterTitle
{
param ($Name,$Filter)
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $Name  -RecipientFilter {(Title -like $Filter)}
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -RecipientFilter {(RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -or (RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox')}
}
`code`
Search for "Dyn" do not get any hit, should give 3 hits
Search for "Get-Dynam" do not get any hit, should get 2 hits

Comment: @AndersNorén can you paste it in pastebin , coz code is not formatted properly in comment.

Comment: I pasted your code in vscode , and searched for `Dyn` i am able to get results https://imgur.com/a/QaTClon

Comment: That is really weird, I get no hits at all
https://imgur.com/a/lfgofPq
https://imgur.com/a/A2LyVHq

Comment: @AndersNorén what's your version of vscode ? I think you might wanna reset vscode and install the latest one

Comment: se initial post, I just installed the latest version last week with "User setup" (uninstalled previous version first)

Comment: @AndersNorén strange